# How to hide input from user inside a textfield

Tags: 7, forms

I need text inside a textfield FAPI form element to be obscured visually, just like the password field when you type into it.

[image]

[password](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#password) FAPI form element does not have proper functionality for what i need, I need textfield functionality but with the ability to hide the input from user.

Is this possible with Drupal 7 FAPI?

Comment: You could have it as textfield initially then convert the field type using jQuery after load, although I'm not sure if the Form API will care about that or not. But it's easy to check. If you don't care about users who have their JS turned off essentially :)

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Be clear in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS style to implement this.

However, currently, only Chrome supplies "-webkit-text-security" could do this. I find someone has some [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/estelle/8WpNg/):   https://jsfiddle.net/estelle/8WpNg/